# Is $\mathbb{E}(X\cdot I_{\{X \geq a\}} = \int\limits_{a}^\infty P(X \geq x) dx, a \geq 0$ for non negative RV $X$?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

For $a=0$, the solution is well known and I was able to show it both with integration by parts and Fubini's theorem. For $a > 0$ I could not establish the equality. Any hints?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Put $Y=X\cdot I_{X\geq a}$ and integrate from zero.
$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{E}(X\cdot I_{X\geq a})&=\mathbb{E}(Y)\\
&=\int_0^{\infty}P(Y\geq x)\,dx\\
&=\int_0^{\infty}P(X\geq x\,\hbox{and}\,X\geq a)\,dx\\
&=\int_a^{\infty}P(X\geq x)\,dx
\end{aligned}$$